# Excel Formula Auto-Update When Columns Added

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two formulas, (currently) one in cell O2 and one in cell P2 which do not auto-update when I add a column (next week they will be in P2 and Q2).  
For example, when if I right click on column O2 and say add column, the formulas are pushed to P2 and Q2, and they exclude the new column added (in this instance O2).  
Is their a way of having my formulas auto-add the "new" column added in the calculation?

Formula 1: `=SUM(B2:N2)`
Formula 2: `=COUNTIF(B2:N2, "<>0")-COUNTBLANK(B2:N2)`

Comment: Look at `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` and related functions.

Comment: @blm - How would I use indirect or offset when the ending cell is always changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first formula (sum): (for B to N in O)

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))
```

the second one: (for B to N in P)

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-2)), "<>0")-COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-2)))
```

if you want to autofill the formulas down, change all the `"B2:"` to `"B"&ROW()&":"`

Comment: to copy down is that applicable for both formulas or only the bottom formula you provided?

Comment: for both... jou just need to change each `"B2:"` in the formulas

Answer (score 0):

Use something like (assuming cell O2 has your formula) `=SUM(INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(2,COLUMN(OFFSET(O2,0,-1)))))`